# Paradoxical time intervals in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to programming (python) As a learning exercise, I wrote a Tkinter program to measure the time between two "simultaneous" keypresses. I wanted to see how much of the measured time was artifactual from the actual processing of the program, so I removed the actual input and I just have the program simulate one keypress after another. Got a short interval as expected (25-35 microseconds). Here's the code that gave me that (just the important part, not the whole program):

```
def buttonPress1(event):
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    asec = a.microsecond
    press1.set(asec) 
    onePressed.set(True)
    if onePressed.get() == True and twoPressed.get() == True:
        difference()
    b = datetime.datetime.now()
    bsec = b.microsecond
    press2.set(bsec)
    twoPressed.set(True)
    if onePressed.get() == True and twoPressed.get() == True:
        difference()    



def difference():
    dif = abs(press1.get() - press2.get())  # This is difference in times. Around 30 microseconds
    resultStr = str(dif) + " microseconds"  
    result.set(resultStr)                   # Result is then displayed in a label widget
    onePressed.set(False)
    twoPressed.set(False)
```

Then I wanted to see how much the complexity of that code was adding to the interval, so I tried a real simple example, but strangely, I'm getting longer intervals (around 300 microseconds), which is the complete opposite of what I expected. Here's that code:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
asec = a.microsecond
bsec = b.microsecond
print bsec-asec   # result is around 300 microseconds
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: `dt.microseconds` is the microsecond *component* of a `datetime` object - it's *not* the entire datetime represented in microseconds.

Comment: Also, `time.time()` is a lot easier to use in situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`datetime.microsecond`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.microsecond) is the microsecond *component* of a `datetime` object - it's *not* the entire datetime represented in microseconds.

In order to get the difference between to `datetime` objects, simply subtract them and you'll get a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object:

```
>>> d1 = datetime.now()
>>> d2 = datetime.now()
>>> delta = d2 - d1
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(0, 12, 431220)
>>> delta.seconds
12
>>> delta.microseconds
431220
```

So the difference here is `12.4` seconds, or `12` seconds and `431220` microseconds.

For measuring elapsed time between two events however, [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) is easier to use, as stated by *@CasualDemon* in the comments:

```
>>> import time
>>> start = time.time()
>>> end = time.time()
>>> elapsed = end - start
>>> elapsed
5.727240085601807    # in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use threads for this. Create thread for keys and in each thread you can calculate time between key strokes. For more explanation you watch my video for this exact solution.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDGYM8LeZh8

See the code below:

```
import keyboard # keyboard library
import string   # string for capturing keyboard key codes
import time     # for capturing time

from threading import * # threads for keypresses

# get the keys
keys = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

# key listener
def listen(key):
    while True:
        global timeda   # global variable for storing time for 1st keypress
        global newda    # global variable for storing time for next keypress

        keyboard.wait(key)  # when key is presses

        # check if variables are defined
        try:
            timeda
            newda

        # this will run for the first keypress only so assign initial time to variable

        except NameError:
            timeda = time.time()
            newda  = time.time()
            print("First key is pressed at "+str(round(newda,2)))
            print('\n==========\n')

        # for all keypresses except for the first will record time here
        else:
            newda = time.time()         # assign time for next keypressed
            newtime = newda - timeda    # get difference between two keys presses

            # just to test time of first keypress
            print("Previous keypress was at "+str(round(timeda,2)))

            # just to test time of next keypress
            print("Current keypress is at "+ str(round(newda,2)))

            # convert time into seconds
            newtime = newtime % 60

            print("Difference between two keypresses is "+str(round(newtime,2)))
            print('\n==========\n')     # need some space for printing difference 
            timeda = time.time()

# creating threads for keys and assigning event and args 
threads = [Thread(target=listen, kwargs={'key':key}) for key in keys]

# calling each thread
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()


# thats it
```